# MFC send signals between objects

Tags: c++, mfc, handler, signals

I have to send signal and data between two objects. The reciever have to handle it.
Can i send signals between objects in MFC? Does it exist a Messenger or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Message Maps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0812b0wa%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)** has a section on **User Defined Windows Messages** that covers your question

Answer (score 0):

If the objects are owned by the UI thread, the approach is to register your own messages with RegisterWindowsMessage then use PostMessage to send messages to the main application window. A message handler in the main window class can then forward the call to a handler in the target object.  See "Message Maps" link in other answer.

If the objects are created/owned by different threads instead of all being owned by the UI thread, the Message Map answer doesn't work.  In that case you need to use callbacks and manage the thread synchronization yourself, or use a 3rd-party library.